# How to start section numbering at 0.0?

Tags: sectioning

How do I change the first index of the sections to be 0? I have already tried `\setcounter{section}{-1}`. This gives me **1.0 Section**.

However I want **0.1 Section**.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you don't give many clues but presumably if your section is numbered 1.x then the 1 is the chapter number so \setcounter{chapter}{-1} before the `\chapter`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\section{Alpha}
\section{Beta}
\chapter{B}
\section{Gamma}
\section{Delta}
\end{document}
```